# different applications split by areas?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-3-areas

I already have programmed some small applications, the database design was simple, just one normalized database containing all the datas I need for the application.

Now I want to try to programm something bigger:

There should be 4 websites build with MVC3. All the websites should use only one SQL-Membership-Database and some tables like contacts and so on should be shared between the different pages too.

Now my question is: how to start?

**Should I put all the Applications into one MVC3-application and just separate them by using areas?**

Is there anyone who have got tipps or experiences in creating huge (for me its huge ;-)) applications like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your idea to use areas could very well work. You might need to create some custom roles to restrict access to the four areas.

You will want to do a search on asp.net mvc multi-tenancy. This link http://weblogs.asp.net/zowens/archive/2010/05/26/multi-tenant-asp-net-mvc-introduction.aspx begins a whole series on multi-tenancy.